# Mongoose - populate with other then id

Tags: mongoose

I have these two simplified schema which I'd like to "join" based on ip address.

```
var personSchema = Schema({
  name: String,
  ip: String
});

var logSchema = Schema({
  message: String,
  ip: String
});
```

It would work if person._id was the ip address. But it's not an options for me.

Currently I've solved the problem the way that when new log is saved, I search the person and add reference to log. Schema is then like this:

```
var logSchema = Schema({
  message: String,
  ip: String,
  person: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }
});
```

I've read mongoose [Populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) documentation, [Document#populated](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populated) and [Model.populate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate). I'm still not sure if it is possible or not. This example is very simplified, I use mapReduce and grouping on log collection and therefore population would be great for me.

I've also read [Database references](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/#DatabaseReferences-SimpleDirect/ManualLinking&gsc.tab=0) and it seems to me that the only option is to populate based on _id. But it's pure mongodb and maybe there is another possiblity using mongoose?

Is it possible to populate query not based on _id field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB does not support joins. So `.populate` just makes another query, therefore the best solution for you is to make another query manually.

Comment: Do you think that it's better to make another query then to save person reference within each log record?

Comment: @Mr.Pohoda It doesn't really help you, since you still have to make a seperate query (`.populate` does it for you). And it will be harder to maintain such db structure. Maybe I wasn't clear enough: make a seperate query **instead of** using `.populate`.

Comment: why does populate use less memory then findOne? I just queried 200,000 entries(larger makes easier to see difference) and my mongod process when using populate never goes over 23% however when I use the findOne property it hits almost 100% of cpu allowed?

Comment: Mongo 3.2 does support the aggregate $lookup which is much like a join

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB 3.2 introduces a $lookup aggregate.  You can use this with mongoose also.  This is an example of how to use it with a conditional `find` also:

```
  Log.aggregate(
      { $match: {log_property: 'value'}},
      { $lookup: {from: 'person', localField: 'ip', foreignField: 'ip', as: 'user'} }
    ).exec( function (err, logs) {
      if (err) {
        next(err);
      }

      res.json(logs);
    }
  );
```

In the above example, the `user` property on each log will be filled in with the person from the matching Person model document